# Group XML nodes with the same name under the same container node

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, json.net

I am developing an application in Visual Studio with `C#`. The app converts from `JSON` to `XML`. After the conversion, in some cases I get a `XML` like this.

```
<root>
    <row>
        <id>0001</id>
        <type>donut</type>
        <name>Cake</name>
        <ppu>0.55</ppu>
        <topping>
            <id>5001</id>
            <type>None</type>
        </topping>
        <topping>
            <id>5002</id>
            <type>Glazed</type>
        </topping>
        <topping>
            <id>5005</id>
            <type>Sugar</type>
        </topping>
        <topping>
            <id>5007</id>
            <type>Powdered Sugar</type>
        </topping>
        <topping>
            <id>5006</id>
            <type>Chocolate with Sprinkles</type>
        </topping>
        <topping>
            <id>5003</id>
            <type>Chocolate</type>
        </topping>
        <topping>
            <id>5004</id>
            <type>Maple</type>
        </topping>
    </row>
</root>
```

As you can see, there are several nodes with the same name and I want to have this `XML` output.

```
 <root>
    <row>
        <id>0001</id>
        <type>donut</type>
        <name>Cake</name>
        <ppu>0.55</ppu>
        <toppings>
            <topping>
                <id>5001</id>
                <type>None</type>
            </topping>
            <topping>
                <id>5002</id>
                <type>Glazed</type>
            </topping>
            <topping>
                <id>5005</id>
                <type>Sugar</type>
            </topping>
            <topping>
                <id>5007</id>
                <type>Powdered Sugar</type>
            </topping>
            <topping>
                <id>5006</id>
                <type>Chocolate with Sprinkles</type>
            </topping>
            <topping>
                <id>5003</id>
                <type>Chocolate</type>
            </topping>
            <topping>
                <id>5004</id>
                <type>Maple</type>
            </topping>
        </toppings>
    </row>
</root>
```

Using C#, How can I group nodes with the same name under one container node?

Comment: How do you want to exactly to group them?

Comment: I want to create a container node for those nodes. Sorry, I didn't mention

Comment: can you maybe add a xml which shows how the result should look?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your expected output? What's the container called?  Is it just for topping, or any element that occurs more than once? Do all elements have to be siblings?

Comment: I have just added an example of the output. 

The container has to be a generic name, it does not matter what name it has.
It has to be the same for each group of nodes. For example if i have another group like "topping", I want to group them under another container node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // or XDocument.Load(filename);

var toppings = doc.Root.Element("row").Elements("topping").ToList();

toppings.Remove();

doc.Root.Element("row").Element("ppu").AddAfterSelf(new XElement("toppings", toppings));
// in the doc we have resulting xml
```

---

Ok, try this for every case.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); // or XDocument.Load(filename);
traverse(doc.Root);
```

```
void traverse(XElement elem)
{
    foreach (var e in elem.Elements())
    {
        traverse(e);
    }

    var groups = elem.Elements().GroupBy(e => e.Name);
    foreach (var g in groups)
    {
        if (g.Count() > 1)
        {
            var sameNodes = g.ToList();
            sameNodes.Remove();
            elem.AddFirst(new XElement(g.Key + "s", sameNodes));
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not preserve the order of elements. It always inserts a group of nodes with the same names in the beginning.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, but it works only for this case. How could I do this for every case? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @FranciscoFischer - see update.

Comment: Thanks! It works like this